# How to copy existing local database to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I've just successfully deployed my Node.js app to Heroku. My next goal is to also copy local mongo database so I can have some initial data.

How can I accomplish that? I've went through Heroku docs and there is nothing which mentions that. On Heroku I am using `mLab MongoDB` add-on.

Answer (score 0):

To restore mongoDB to mlab, 
you need to use mongo restore command issued on your local dev system

```
mongorestore -h host.mlab.com:13024 -d dataBAseName -u <user> -p <password> <input db directory>
```